# BenchmarkDotNet. Is it possible to include not warmed up results?

Tags: c#, benchmarking, benchmarkdotnet

Assume we have some big method which is very slow on a cold start. 
Can we do such benchmarks and see not warmed up results?

Comment: The answer is yes, in fact there is a setting that does just that, have you looked at the documentation? Its on the front page of the wiki

Comment: @TheGeneral you are right. I found it and added answer to my own question below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was noted - it is possible and there is some info in official docs.

```
[MinColumn, MaxColumn]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[SimpleJob(RunStrategy.ColdStart, launchCount: 3,
    warmupCount: 0, targetCount: 6)]
public class SomeBenchmark
{
    [Benchmark]
    public string Benchmark()
    {
    }
}
```